Cumulative unique ids in SAS
In SAS how to assign IDs that will not be repeated in each SELECT.
For example, I have table like this (3 rows, 3 columns, first column is IDs):
100000000000 Dylan dylan@mail.com
100000000001 Rebel rebel@mail.com 
100000000002 Example example@mail.com
When I select new data, for example I input again same 3 rows, id (1 column) must be increase in every SELECT or something like this:
100000000003 Dylan dylan@mail.com
100000000004 Rebel rebel@mail.com 
100000000005 Example example@mail.com 
Is it means I need cumulative table or what?
How I can solve this case?
I tried save last ID to work table. But i think it's not safe.

What is the actual problem you are trying to solve.  How does making these unique numbers help solve that problem?  How are you inputting new data? Why are you adding new data? What type of analysis are you doing?

Hi Dylan, your question is not really applicable.
The purpose of a SELECT statement is to... select some data stored a table (or a dataset)
The problematic you have concerns HOW you INSERT/STORE data in that table, assigning a unique identifier.

SAS does not have a SEQUENCE object as might be found in a RDBMS.  There are certain techniques and tricks that can be used depending on the situation.  Achieving safe atomic sequence delivery based on a SAS data set in a multi-user or parallel session situation can be difficult.

You want to increment an ID every time a select statement is run? You'd basically need two pieces of code: one to select the data, then another to modify or increment the ID. Or you'd need to see if your database has some sort of trigger that can be run to automatically increment all IDs when you run a select statement but honestly I don't know why you'd want to do this. Sounds like a real headache to maintain.
